# Enable gestures at Samsung Ativ Book 2

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, touchpad, gestures

How to enable gestures to fully use multitouch in a Samsung Ativ Book 2?

Couldn't find solution online maybe some of you had similar problem.

I'm using Windows 8.1.

Comment: Thank you. It's just Windows 8.1, rather no RTM. I'll try to download them from samsung's website.

Comment: OK, thank you! Actually, installing drivers from samsungs website worked!

Comment: Post an answer with a link to the drivers you installed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link: http://www.samsung.com/nz/support/model/NP270E5E-X01AU-downloads
I downloaded SW Update from left menu.